# React Material-UI: 'Check the render method of `Paperbase`'

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material-UI's paperbase premium theme:

https://material-ui.com/premium-themes/paperbase/

and looking at the source code I tried doing the following:

```
// App.tsx

import * as React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Paperbase from './components/Paperbase'

class App extends React.Component {
  public render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
      <Paperbase />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;



// Paperbase.js

import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { createMuiTheme, withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import Hidden from '@material-ui/core/Hidden';
import Navigator from './Navigator';
import Content from './Content';
import Header from './Header';

let theme = createMuiTheme({
  typography: {
    h5: {
      fontWeight: 500,
      fontSize: 26,
      letterSpacing: 0.5,
    },
  },
  palette: {
    primary: {
      light: '#63ccff',
      main: '#009be5',
      dark: '#006db3',
    },
  },
  shape: {
    borderRadius: 8,
  },
});

theme = {
  ...theme,
  overrides: {
    MuiDrawer: {
      paper: {
        backgroundColor: '#18202c',
      },
    },
    MuiButton: {
      label: {
        textTransform: 'initial',
      },
      contained: {
        boxShadow: 'none',
        '&:active': {
          boxShadow: 'none',
        },
      },
    },
    MuiTabs: {
      root: {
        // marginLeft: theme.spacing(1),
      },
      indicator: {
        height: 3,
        borderTopLeftRadius: 3,
        borderTopRightRadius: 3,
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.common.white,
      },
    },
    MuiTab: {
      root: {
        textTransform: 'initial',
        margin: '0 16px',
        minWidth: 0,
        padding: 0,
        [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
          padding: 0,
          minWidth: 0,
        },
      },
    },
    MuiIconButton: {
      root: {
        // padding: theme.spacing(1),
      },
    },
    MuiTooltip: {
      tooltip: {
        borderRadius: 4,
      },
    },
    MuiDivider: {
      root: {
        backgroundColor: '#404854',
      },
    },
    MuiListItemText: {
      primary: {
        fontWeight: theme.typography.fontWeightMedium,
      },
    },
    MuiListItemIcon: {
      root: {
        color: 'inherit',
        marginRight: 0,
        '& svg': {
          fontSize: 20,
        },
      },
    },
    MuiAvatar: {
      root: {
        width: 32,
        height: 32,
      },
    },
  },
  props: {
    MuiTab: {
      disableRipple: true,
    },
  },
  mixins: {
    ...theme.mixins,
    toolbar: {
      minHeight: 48,
    },
  },
};

const drawerWidth = 256;

const styles = {
  root: {
    display: 'flex',
    minHeight: '100vh',
  }
};

class Paperbase extends React.Component {
  state = {
    mobileOpen: false,
  };

  handleDrawerToggle = () => {
    this.setState(state => ({ mobileOpen: !state.mobileOpen }));
  };

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;

    return (
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <div className={classes.root}>
          <CssBaseline />
          <nav className={classes.drawer}>
            <Hidden smUp implementation="js">
              <Navigator
                PaperProps={{ style: { width: drawerWidth } }}
                variant="temporary"
                open={this.state.mobileOpen}
                onClose={this.handleDrawerToggle}
              />
            </Hidden>
            <Hidden xsDown implementation="css">
              <Navigator PaperProps={{ style: { width: drawerWidth } }} />
            </Hidden>
          </nav>
          <div className={classes.appContent}>
            <Header onDrawerToggle={this.handleDrawerToggle} />
            <main className={classes.mainContent}>
              <Content />
            </main>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

Paperbase.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(Paperbase);
```

and I am getting an error saying:

```
Check the render method of `Paperbase`.
```

I am very new to React and trying to use this material ui theme in my sample app. But, not sure what is going on here and why it is complaining about the render method. I tried looking on the internet about the possible solutions but couldnt find anything that applies to this case. Can somebody help in troubleshooting this? I'm certainly doing something stupid.

Comment: What is the full error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `ThemeProvider` with `MuiThemeProvider`, in order to use `ThemeProvider` you should use:

```
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/styles';
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! It works perfectly when I removed ThemeProvider and used MuiThemeProvider. Btw, what is the difference between ThemeProvider and MuiThemeProvider? Also, when I tried importing ThemeProvider from '@material-ui/styles', I saw an error saying that styles does not exist in material-ui. The folder structure might have changed, or maybe I did not install the right npm module.

Comment: @Aiguo `ThemeProvider` is part of `@material-ui/styles` that will be the default style implementation for the core components in Material-UI v4, for more information: [https://material-ui.com/css-in-js/basics/](https://material-ui.com/css-in-js/basics/)